# Python 3 : Two classes with comon __init_subclass__()

Tags: python-3.x, oop, metaprogramming

I have two classes with a common `__init_subclass__()` method. The `__init_subclass__()` checks whether the inheriting class have some class variables set (but this could be even more complex code in the end; I just wanted to make an example):

```py
class A():
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        # Validate required class variables
        required_class_variables = [
            "a",
            "b",
        ]
        for required_class_variable in required_class_variables:
            if not hasattr(cls, required_class_variable):
                raise TypeError(
                    f'Class {cls} lacks `{required_class_variable}` \
                    class attribute'
                )

class B():
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        # Validate required class variables
        required_class_variables = [
            "a",
            "b",
        ]
        for required_class_variable in required_class_variables:
            if not hasattr(cls, required_class_variable):
                raise TypeError(
                    f'Class {cls} lacks `{required_class_variable}` \
                    class attribute'
                )
```

Of course, `A` and `B` have more methods, which I just omit for the sake of a minimum example. How can I avoid code repetition here? I cannot make `A` and `B` inherit from a common base class and define the `__init_subclass__`  there, because that would force `A` and `B` to have the required_class_variables, whereas I want to have the child classes of `A` and `B` to have them. (This holds true, even if that base class is an Abstract Base Class.)

Is there a way to achieve that with `__init_subclass__`? Or do I need to work with a metaclass or a class decorator, finally?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a static method to the Base class and call this method on the `__init_subclass__()` of `A` and `B`respectively, like so:

```py
class Base:
    @staticmethod
    def init_subclass(cls):
        required_class_variables = ["a", "b"]
        for required_class_variable in required_class_variables:
            if not hasattr(cls, required_class_variable):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"{cls} lacks required class variable"
                    f"{required_class_variable}!"
                )


class A(Base):
   def __init_subclass__(cls):
       Base.init_subclass(cls)


class B(Base):
   def __init_subclass__(cls):
       Base.init_subclass(cls)
```